# Using Angular Service in MEANJS 0.4.2

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I have a, maybe simple, problem. I worked with services in Angular before but now a ran into problems using a MEANJS Yeoman Generator project. What i need to to is to use data of an array from a specific module in another module, so that i can ng-repeat over this inside the view of the other model.

Where exactly do i bring in the array inside the service?

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('patients')

  .factory('PatientsService', PatientsService);

  PatientsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function PatientsService($resource) {
    return $resource('api/patients/:patientId', {
      patientId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

I found nothing inside the MEANJS Doc so far and neither here (only from older MEANJS versions with another service structure).

Here is what i would like to bring inside the service:

```
  // Shows a List of useable avatars on Patient creation
    $scope.avatars = [
      { value:'1', name: 'modules/patients/client/img/avatar/avatar1.png' },
      { value:'2', name: 'modules/patients/client/img/avatar/avatar2.png' },
      { value:'3', name: 'modules/patients/client/img/avatar/avatar3.png' },
      { value:'4', name: 'modules/patients/client/img/avatar/avatar4.png' },
      { value:'5', name: 'modules/patients/client/img/avatar/avatar5.png' },
      { value:'6', name: 'modules/patients/client/img/avatar/avatar6.png' }
    ];
```

I would like to use the avatars in the home.client view an the PatientsService is already injected inside the home.client controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service above simply returns a `$resource`. Instead, the service could return a plain old Javascript object (or a class) that had various properties. Among them would be a property containing the array of avatars, and another containing the `$resource`:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('patients')

  .factory('PatientsService', PatientsService);

  PatientsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function PatientsService($resource) {
    return {
      avatars: [ {value: 0, ... } ],
      resource: $resource('api/patients/:patientId', {
          patientId: '@_id'
        }, {
          update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
      })
    }

  }
})();
```

Comment: oh, i see, this is indeed easy but i tried it the complet wrong way! thanks a lot

Comment: do you know if i need to change anything else in order to use the $resources throughout the app. It seems that the cannot be used anymore?!

Comment: git it myself. i think you can use it with both. avatas as object and resources just as they where after the object.

Comment: `return {
      avatars: [
        { value:'1', ... }
      ]
    },
    $resource('api/patients/:patientId', {
      patientId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });`